Gradient of Lagrangian function (tensor calculus)
I have the following lagrangian function:
$\mathscr{L} = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{ij} u_i K_{ij} u_j - F_i w_i + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{ijk} E_k~ \hat{g}_{kij}~ \partial_i u_j  + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{ijk} E_i~ \hat{d}_{ij} ~E_j - \lambda_i u_i\bigr\rvert_{\Gamma_c} +\lambda_i B_{ij} u_j^R$
the symbol  $\bigr\rvert_{\Gamma_c}$ in $u_i\bigr\rvert_{\Gamma_c}$ refers to the vector values on the interface $\Gamma_c$.
I need to compute the gradient of the lagrangian function with respect to two of its arguments: $\textbf{u}$ which denotes the displacement vector and contains the displacement values of the nodal points of a material, and $\textbf{u}^R$, which denotes the displacement vector of a reference point $R$ and in the matrix notation it is represented by:
$\textbf{u}^R =$ \begin{bmatrix}
w_x\\
w_z\\
\theta\\
\end{bmatrix}
where $w_x$ and $w_z$ are components of the translation vector $\vec{w}$ and $\theta$ is angle of rotation of reference point $R$.
I have problem with computing the gradients (they are taken to be zero since I aim to use for optimization, finding a minimum):
$\nabla_{\textbf{u}} \mathcal{L}  = 0\\
\nabla_{\textbf{u}^R} \mathcal{L} = 0$
For the first equation, I have tried to solve it this way:
$\partial_{u_l} \mathscr{L}  = 0\\
K_{il} u_l +  {?}   - \lambda_l  = 0$
And with the second equation:
$            \partial_{u_l^R} \mathscr{L}  = 0~,\\
            - F_i \delta_{li} + \lambda_i B_{ij} \delta_{jl}  = 0~,\\
           - F_l + \lambda_i B_{il}  = 0~,\\
           F_l  = \lambda_i B_{il} ~,\\
           \vec{F}  = \boldsymbol{\lambda}^T \boldsymbol{B}$
I am confused.
